# How can I increase the spacing between a fermata and the note in Lilypond?

Tags: lilypond

I'm notating a piece of music with Lilypond, and am running into an issue where the fermata symbol is consistently too close to the note it's attached to. The problem is emphasised by some nearby grace notes.

The code I'm using is these two lines (wrapped up in two separate staves inside a `PianoStaff`):

```
\appoggiatura { c16 e g } <c, e g>1.\fermata |

\appoggiatura { c8 g' } <c, g'>1.\fermata |
```

Here's the result:

[image: A few notes, with a fermata almost touching them.]

As you can see, the fermata on the lower note is almost touching the note, and the upper one isn't much better. I've tried using `\tweak Y-offset`, and it seems to work for an earlier fermata (using something like `c2-\tweak Y-offset #2.5 \fermata`), but doing the same thing here just makes the fermata sit right in the middle of the staff, colliding with the notes.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out you *can* use `\tweak`, but `Y-offset` is not the way to go – `padding` works much better. There's probably a better way to do it, but if so, I don't know it.

```
\appoggiatura { c16 e g } <c, e g>1.-\tweak padding #0.5 \fermata

\appoggiatura { c8 g' } <c, g'>1.-\tweak padding #0.5 \fermata
```

[image: A few notes, with a fermata a reasonable distance away.]